# How do I constrain an animation to the path of the torus knot extended primitive

Tags: 3dsmax, autodesk

I'm trying to map a repeating object over the path of a torus knot, any one familiar with this process?

I understand how to map an object along a path with "Path Constraints" and "Snapshots" but I can't seem to figure out how to do this with a primitive like the torus knot.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a loop of edges all around the torus knot, one continuous line made of multiple edges, then convert that selection to spline, this gives you a spline that follows the surface of the torus knot, then you can use path constraint and select the spline, so that your object uses that spline as a path.